# projective-Klein geometry book?

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation, projective-geometry

I would like to study projective geometry as a Klein's geometry.

I think that "Notes on Geometry" by Rees is a good one but I need more details.

What is the best book to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful book directly related to this topic is *Differential Geometry: Cartan's Generalization of Klein's Erlangen Program*, by R.W.Sharpe.

Here is a link to a relevant paper about two papers by Felix Klein on Non-Euclidean geometry, projective geometry, and related works:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.7309.pdf

Additional helpful books:

*Projective and Cayley-Klein Geometries*, by by Arkadij L. Onishchik and Rolf Sulanke .

*Perspectives on Projective Geometry: A Guided Tour Through Real and Complex Geometry*, by Jürgen Richter-Gebert .